# Passing quiz score using html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I need some help in developing a quiz using HTML.
Here is the code, if you require pictures I can provide them, I need some help getting the score counter to count over around 10 pages, and it keeps the right score so for a correct answer it will be 1, for a wrong answer it will be -0.25. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>     {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body{
      background-image: url('background.png');
      font-family: sans-serif: ;
    
  }
  button{
      
    font:inherit;
    font-size:100%;
    color:black;
    line-height:normal;
    vertical-align:baseline
    
  }
  #hello{
    width: 96%;
    background-color: palegreen;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 6px double limegreen;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  #quiz{
    position: relative
         width: 96%;
 
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 6px double black;
    border-radius: 10px;;
  }
  h1{
    font-size: 28px;
    clear: both;
  }
  #quiz h1{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: yellowF;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px grey);
      background-image: "background.img"
  }
  .option{
    background-color: Black;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid Black ;
  }
  #quiz button{
    width: 100%;
    display: block ;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #quiz .option:hover{
    background: white;
    color: lightgreen ;
    border: 2px solid lightgreen;
  }
  .green{
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid green;
    color: green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  .green:before,#score:before{
    content: 'Correct ✔️ ';
  }
  .red{
    background-color: white;
    
  }
  .red:before,#wrong:before{
    content:'Incorrect ✖️ ';
  }
  .score{
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .wrong{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #show button{
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  #start{
    text-align: center;
  }
  #start button{
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .hidden{
    display: none;
  }
  #sticky{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0px auto 20px auto;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #sticky span{
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 4px;
  }
  #fscore{
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
        p{font-size: 30px
        }
        p1 {font-size: 30px}
        p2{font-size: 30px}
    </style>
    <title>Next Question</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<body>
    <div id="main">
  <div id="hello">
    

    <br />
    <div id="start">
      <button type="button">Start Quiz</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Quiz Start-->
  <div id="quiz" class="hidden">
  <div id="sticky">
     <span class="wrong"><span id="wrong">0</span></span>
    <span class="score"><span id="score">0</span></span>
  </div>
    
    
  <h1>1. What does CPU stand for?</h1> 
    <div class="choose">
      <button class="option" value="wrong" type="radio">Certain process units</button>
      <button class="option" value="wrong" type="radio">Central processing unix</button>
      <button type="radio" class="option" value="right">Central processing unit</button>
      <button class="option" value="wrong" type="button">Computer's proessing unit</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    
  
    <br />
  <div id="show">
      <button type="button">Show Correct Answers</button>
  </div>
      <form method="get" action="t2.html" hidden>
        <button type="submit">Press to start</button>
    </form>
  <!--Final Score-->
  <div id="fscore">You Scored <span class="fscore">0</span> out of <span  class="total"></span>
   </div>
      
      
       
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>     $(function(){
    var tot = $(".choose").length;
    $(".total").html(tot);//total Score
    $("#start").click(function(){
      $('#hello').addClass('hidden');
      $("#quiz").removeClass('hidden');
      $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#quiz").offset().top
}, 10);//smooth scrolling effect to min quiz
    });
      $(".option").click(function(){
        var score = 0;
        var wrong = 0;
        $(this).removeClass("option");//disable it's css
        $(this)
              .addClass(($(this).val() === "right") ? 'green' : 'red');//right or wrong css
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled",true);//prevent to choose other options
      for (i=0;i<$(".green").length;i++){
         if ($(this).val() === "right"){
           score++;
           $("#score").html(score);//update score
         }
         }
      for (k=0;k<$(".red").length;k++){
         if ($(".red").val() === "wrong"){
           wrong++;
           $("#wrong").html(wrong);//update negative score
         }
         }
        var p = +$("#score").text();
        var m = +$("#wrong").text();
        var n = m*0.25;//0.25marks deducted for each wrong answer
        var t = p-n;//get final score considering negative marking
        $(".fscore").html(t);//update final score
      });
      $("#show button").click(function(){
for (j=0;j<$(".choose").length;j++) {
  $(':button[value="right"]').addClass('green')
     .removeClass("option");//show correct option
}
$('.choose>button').attr("disabled",true);//disable all Buttons
      });
  });
   
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: You can use local storage

Comment: How would I got about doing this, I am very new to coding. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Why the dislike? Obviously OP is a new contributor and the community should be more lenient to him.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to store data in the client's web browser. Data saved using localStorage has no expiry date. It will stay there intact unless deleted. You can read about `localStorage` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

You can do something like this.

1. First, calculate the score on the first page.
2. Assuming you have some kind of button click or simply a click on an element to navigate to the next page. You can add an event listener to this element using JavaScript. This event listener will execute a function which will first, calculate the result on the first page and then store it in the web browser using `localStorage` like this `localStorage.setItem("score", quizScore);`
3. After navigating to the next page you can run a function when the page completely loads that retrieves this score using this `var score = localStorage.getItem("score");`
4. Then you can display the current score, carry on with the quiz, calculate the result, add it to the previous score, update the key `score` value, and repeat the first, second, third, and fourth steps for all the future pages again until you have calculated the final score of the quiz.
5. Lastly, you can retrieve the final value, show it to the client in whatever way you like, and delete it using `localStorage.removeItem("score");` if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem("score", 1.5);
// Retrieve
var cnt =  localStorage.getItem("score");
console.log(cnt)
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varm9uwo/)